# Can you use Create-React-App npm start with nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm very new to React and node.js.

I want to run a node.js server that serves up React.js pages/views.

When I use 'create-react-app' and then 'npm start' do I need to then start my node server as well, or do I need to use 'npm run build' before it will work with the node.js server?

I like how it auto-updates your react.js pages after 'npm start' when you make changes to the code.

I'm just wondering if I have to run the 'npm run build' command every time I make a change.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to run `npm run build` command each time as this command is used when you're ready to ship your code to production environment.

In a `create-react-app` project, you get `hot reloading` out of the box when developing locally (after running `npm start`). In other words, when the local server is running, every time you make a change the browser will automatically reload.

---

**From the create-react-app documentation:**

> npm start: 
>   Runs the app in the development mode. Open http://localhost:3000 to view it in the browser.
>
> The page will reload if you make edits. You will also see any lint errors in the console.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts#npm-start

Comment: So then after I run 'npm start', I can run the express/node server.js on a different port and then test passing data between the backend and the front end?

Comment: That's correct, you can't run the nodejs backend server on the same port as the front-end. Once the nodejs server is running, you can make API calls from the frontend but make sure CORS is properly defined otherwise you get a `Cross-Origin` error.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!  I've been researching this for days.  I also found this article to help me understand CORS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS  Thanks again!